# Reading files from encrypted OBB file

Tags: android, encryption, apk-expansion-files

I created an encrypted OBB file from the JOBB tool and I am trying to access the files inside of it, there are some images "image1.jpg, image2.jpg" etc. So far I am able to successfully mount it with:

```
public void mountExpansion() {
    final StorageManager storageManager  = (StorageManager) this.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);


    String packageName = "com.nick.app";
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/obb/" + packageName + "/" + "main."
            + getString(R.string.apk_expansion_version) + "." + packageName + ".obb";
    final File mainFile = new File(filePath);
    if (mainFile.exists()) {
        Log.d("STORAGE", "FILE: " + filePath + " Exists");
    } else {
        Log.d("STORAGE", "FILE: " + filePath + " DOESNT EXIST");
    }

    String key = "123456";
    if (!storageManager.isObbMounted(mainFile.getAbsolutePath())) {
        if (mainFile.exists()) {
            if(storageManager.mountObb(mainFile.getAbsolutePath(), key,
                    new OnObbStateChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onObbStateChange(String path, int state) {
                            super.onObbStateChange(path, state);
                            Log.d("PATH = ",path);
                            Log.d("STATE = ", state+"");
                            expansionFilePath = storageManager.getMountedObbPath(path);
                            if (state == OnObbStateChangeListener.MOUNTED) {
                                expansionFilePath = storageManager
                                        .getMountedObbPath(path);
                                Log.d("STORAGE","-->MOUNTED");
                                Log.d("NICK","length()"+mainFile.length());
                                Log.d("NICK","getAbsolutePath()"+mainFile.getAbsolutePath());
                                Log.d("NICK","isDirectory()"+mainFile.isDirectory());

                            }
                            else {
                                Log.d("##", "Path: " + path + "; state: " + state);
                            }
                        }
                    }))
            {
                Log.d("STORAGE_MNT","SUCCESSFULLY QUEUED");
            }
            else
            {
                Log.d("STORAGE_MNT","FAILED");
            }

        } else {
            Log.d("STORAGE", "Patch file not found");
        }
    }



}
```

And in my log I see the state "1" returned from `OnObbStateChangeListener` indicating the encrypted OBB file is successfully mounted. However at this point I am at a loss for how I can access the files inside of it and make use of them. For example load them into an `ImageView` etc. Any suggestions for what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

```
storageManager.mountObb(main.getPath(), null, new OnObbStateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onObbStateChange(String path, int state) {
        super.onObbStateChange(path, state);
        if (state == MOUNTED) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "obb mounted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            File file = new File(storageManager.getMountedObbPath(path));
        } else
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "mount fail :" + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

The file object is directory to all your files in obb. 
To access those you may call `listFiles()` on it.